# Play Framework evolutions error

Tags: playframework, playframework-evolutions

I added a few evolutions files. Now I get this error:

> [error] p.a.d.e.DefaultEvolutionsApi - You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 33 [ERROR:1064,
>   SQLSTATE:42000]

when I try to launch the server. So I removed the files and recompiled and tried to start the server. The same error is coming again! It was compiling fine before I added those files.

Where is it getting the error from still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because since you had an error, the error has been added in the table play_evolutions of your database. If you delete the last entry of this table and restart the application, it should work fine.